# Regex - match either word/digit or only space within a single word

Tags: .net, regex

below is my current code
I will replace `*` with the regular expression in order for me to do searching,

```
Regex.Match(value, @"([a-zA-Z0-9\s_.,!""'/$\-]+)");
```

I want to make sure the regex only match within a word, instead of across the whole sentences.

```
Keyword: recomm*
Text: recommend on a solution
Result: matched

Keyword: recommend*
Text: recommend on a solution
Result: matched

Keyword: re*om*end
Text: recommend on a solution
Result: matched

Keyword: recommend*on
Text: recommend on a solution
Result: not matched
```

But my regex work fine with the 1st 3 examples, but not the fourth one.
Anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "match within a word, instead of across the whole sentences" ?

Comment: means the * i use to match only within a word, instead of whole sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `\s`, because it matches whitespace. So, just remove that, and you're good to go! =D

Actually if you consider words as those separated by whitespaces, you can use:

```
(\S+)
```

to match anything which is not a space.

Or you can specify the set of characters yourself:

```
([^ \t\r\n]+)
```

Comment: I guess i need to match \s for tab space too

Comment: You can use `\S` then to match non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 2):

I'd remove `\s` from the character class and use `*` delimiter:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_.,!""'/$\-]*)
```

and you can simplify:

```
([\w.,!""'/$-]*)
```